# Output of piped cmd.exe's children lacks

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Piping cmd.exe with a subprocess in order of **embedding a console** works fine in most cases. *When using a stdout.read(1)-thread of course.* However this thread is getting nothing for few commands (i spotted this for python itself as well as for python programms).

I know there are lots of questions about output from children, but this is about loosing a child's child's *(and so on)* output. The output of cmd.exe itself *as well as most of commands* is easily tracked out. Also I can assume that the same occurs for input as the interactive python shell within cmd.exe is not closing when exit() is entered.

This could be a buffering issue - but that would be strange as buffering is disabled for Popen *(and p.stdin.flush() is used as python won't start within p elseways)*. Also this could be caused because of bad inheritance of the processes and their standard i/o streams, but i actually hope it's not.

I can see there could be good use for example code but this is actually *as I mentioned* embedded. So if someone sees a theoretical problem I can skip the process of exporting that code :) However I should add an example even tough this board gives lots of examples relating to cmd.exe and popen. It would take less time than I spent already on googling for the solution.

The basic problem is

```
subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", stdin = -1, stdout = -1, stderr = -2, bufsize=0)
```

that not all children of that subprocess *seem* to be using the pipes. *The cmd starts accepting further commands as soon as it's child has been killed (what's probably ensuring the loss of it's output).*

Comment: The behavings of the interactive python shell within the piped cmd subprocess won't change when python -u is used. Anyways. I'd be happy to - at least - see the problem a bit clearer.

Comment: The buffer issue isn't on the `Popen` end of the pipe. You're overlooking that the child process can fully buffer its output and generally will do so when its stdout isn't an interactive terminal/console. Unless the program provides a way to disable buffering like Python's `-u` option, then you're stuck waiting for it to flush its buffer. On Linux there are standard ways to hook a shared library in at startup to disable buffering (see `stdbuf`), but to my knowledge nothing has been developed for this on Windows. Try [WinPexpect](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home).

Comment: I gave pexpect a try but it does pretty much the same behavoir. Also I assume I can forget about it as it is a windows related problem and -u is not working for some reason. It says `see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'` but that does not help http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u. 

But now I'm even more happy already having been implying the http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/code.html#code.InteractiveInterpreter. I'd recommend doing so as it's awesome for debugging. And I'm amazed of Linux anyways - It's doing way less problems ;)

Comment: But why does that program then even know that it isn't an interactive? :)

Comment: *But why does that program then even know that it isn't an interactive?* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364960(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: OK, you want Python's REPL (interactive shell). python.exe doesn't run its shell if `stdin` isn't interactive, but you can force interactive mode via `-i`. I use this to run the REPL as the SYSTEM account via `psexec -s path\to\python.exe -i` because psexec uses pipes. The `-i` flag also disables buffering on Windows (on Unix it switches to line buffering). In this case you actually don't want `-u` if you're using Python 2 because it also sets `stdin` to binary mode, and the 2.x parser can't handle the Windows `'\r\n'` line endings.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, note that checking for `FILE_TYPE_CHAR`, as the C runtime `isatty` function does, isn't checking for just a console. If you redirect `stdin` to `NUL` or `COM2`, then `isatty` also returns true. I've seen naive code that checks `isatty` when it really wants to check for a console explicitly, such as by calling `GetConsoleMode` on the handle. I think the CRT's `isatty` function is wrong, but that ship has sailed.

Comment: @eryksun the -i option is a good advice. What does python then do if it's not used? just hang idling around? :D And there is no option to -i to get the input printed as well (like cmd itself does)?

Comment: It's tokenizing `stdin` like a regular file, which will never end until you enter `Ctrl+Z` (i.e. `b'\x1a'` or `bytes([26])`) at the start of a line. This is special-cased by the CRT as EOF. This will actually work in Python 2 if you enter some statements followed by `Ctrl+Z`. In Python 3, `stdin` is configured in binary mode, so you'd have to make sure to send `b'\n'` instead of `b'\r\n'` to end a line, else the parser will raise a `SyntaxError`.